# Doctrine / Symfony2 : postSave event?

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine

I have an issue with doctrine 2. I can't find how to achieve a result similar to the function postSave in Doctrine 1.

Basically, what I want to do is to persist, update or remove an entity and once the database is updated I want to perform operation on related entities.

I tried to do it in postPersist, postUpdate and postRemove, but the database is not updated at that point.

I'm using Entity listener, with my own entity listener resolver to inject my own services in my listener.
The onFLush method doesn't seam to work.

On this page http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners there is no mention of postFlush or even onFlush event in entity listener.

If anyone knows how to execute some code AFTER the database is updated I would be very gratefull :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need **lifecycle callbacks**:

- [**Doctrine2 docs**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events)
- [**Symfony2 docs**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks)

I suspect that you need `postUpdate` or `onFlush` (which are described in the first page)

This:

> postUpdate - The postUpdate event occurs after the database update operations to entity data. It is not called for a DQL UPDATE statement.

And this:

> onFlush - The onFlush event occurs after the change-sets of all managed entities are computed. This event is not a lifecycle callback.

Comment: I already used the postUpdate event, but like I said the database is not updated. 
I also already tried the onFLush event but it not called in the listener.

What the doc says is wrong.
"postUpdate - The postUpdate event occurs after the database update operations to entity data." I check the database : nothing updated.

"postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database insert operations. Generated primary key values are available in the postPersist event." I check the database : nothing inserted.

Comment: Ok, can you please add some of code you've tried to your question?

Comment: Ok, I've found how to solve it.
First, I did not see the update or the insert in the database because I did a 'die' before the postFlush event.
Second, the preFlush is a liveCycleCallback when onFlush and postFlush are not. The official documentation needs to be updated.
Third, the object is populated only after the postFlush event :/ meaning that I had to merge so parameters to simulate the population. Thanks.